# How to translate curl -u uasername:password into Java Android?

Tags: java, android, url, authentication, curl

This question may be already asked before but for different issue.
The following cURL command is work fine with shell command:

```
curl -u MyuserName:MyPassword  http://192.168.0.198:8067/startvideo?force=1&tag=20141010-121420
```

I tried to implement it in Java/Android:

```
    private void startRecord() {


    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                            // replace with your url
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.198:8067/startvideo?force=1&tag=20141010-121420");


    //Post Data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "MyuserName"));
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "MyPassword"));


    //Encoding POST data
    try {
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // log exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //making POST request.
    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        // write response to log
        Log.d("Http Post Response:", response.toString());
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // Log exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Log exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

But the app crashed and got the following error:

```
        10-12 12:15:41.245: E/AndroidRuntime(25877): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    10-12 12:15:41.245: E/AndroidRuntime(25877): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service ioio.examples.hello_service.TestService: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    10-12 12:15:41.245: E/AndroidRuntime(25877):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2424)
    10-12 12:15:41.245: E/AndroidRuntime(25877):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:140)
    10-12 12:15:41.245: E/AndroidRuntime(25877):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1319)
    10-12 12:15:41.245: E/AndroidRuntime(25877):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    10-12 12:15:41.245: E/AndroidRuntime(25877):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    10-12 12:15:41.245: E/AndroidRuntime(25877):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
    10-12 12:15:41.245: E/AndroidRuntime(25877):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    10-12 12:15:41.245: E/AndroidRuntime(25877):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    10-12 12:15:41.245: E/AndroidRuntime(25877):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
    10-12 12:15:41.245: E/AndroidRuntime(25877):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
    10-12 12:15:41.245: E/AndroidRuntime(25877):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    10-12 12:15:41.245: E/AndroidRuntime(25877): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    10-12 12:15:41.245: E/AndroidRuntime(25877):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1118)
    10-12 12:15:41.245: E/AndroidRuntime(25877):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
    10-12 12:15:41.245: E/AndroidRuntime(25877):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
    10-12 12:15:41.245: E/AndroidRuntime(25877):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
    10-12 12:15:41.245: E/AndroidRuntime(25877):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
    10-12 12:15:41.245: E/AndroidRuntime(25877):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
    10-12 12:15:41.245: E/AndroidRuntime(25877):    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
    10-12 12:15:41.245: E/AndroidRuntime(25877):    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
    10-12 12:15:41.245: E/AndroidRuntime(25877):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
    10-12 12:15:41.245: E/AndroidRuntime(25877):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
    10-12 12:15:41.245: E/AndroidRuntime(25877):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
    10-12 12:15:41.245: E/AndroidRuntime(25877):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
    10-12 12:15:41.245: E/AndroidRuntime(25877):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:670)
    10-12 12:15:41.245: E/AndroidRuntime(25877):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:509)
    10-12 12:15:41.245: E/AndroidRuntime(25877):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
    10-12 12:15:41.245: E/AndroidRuntime(25877):    at ioio.examples.hello_service.TestService.start_record2(TestService.java:77)
    10-12 12:15:41.245: E/AndroidRuntime(25877):    at ioio.examples.hello_service.TestService.onCreate(TestService.java:34)
    10-12 12:15:41.245: E/AndroidRuntime(25877):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2414)
    10-12 12:15:41.245: E/AndroidRuntime(25877):    ... 10 more
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, do you have idea how to avoid the duplicated issue?

Comment: Read the 800+ voted answer on that question.

Comment: ok, I followed the answers you mentioned and used thread,now no error, but my method above do nothing, I mean it is not same as when I do it in cURL which it record the video??? I didn't get any error in eclipse!